# Interpretation of best subset selection regression model for factor variables with more than 2 levels

Tags: machine-learning, regression, r, categorical-data

I applied the **best subset selection regression model** in R from `leaps` package to my `dat` dataframe. `x` and `y` are factors with 3, and 4 levels, respectively. The result of the summary of the model is like below image.

```
library(leaps)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = as.factor(sample(c(1,2,3), size = 10, TRUE)),
  y = as.factor(sample(c(4,5,6,7), size = 10, TRUE)),
  z = rnorm(10),
  res = rnorm(10)
)
model.full <- regsubsets(res ~ ., data = dat, nvmax = 3)
summary(model.full)
```

summary result:

[image]

I would like to have clear picture of what is going on in the results. Does anyone could help me interpret this result? It is clear that levels 2 and 3 of `x` variable, while not selected for best 1-varibale and 2-varibale models, have been chosen for best 3-variable model. Also, from the model coefficients I can say:

[image]

- Intercept 2.32 is the average value of the `res` for level 1 of `x` variable.
- X2 coefficient -2.41 can be interpreted as the difference in the average `res` between `x` level 2 and `x` level 1.
- X3 coefficient -2.92 can be interpreted as the difference in the average `res` between `x` level 3 and `x` level 1.

Does this interpretation correct?

It is just a hypothetical situation. My actual problem is that I have many factor variables with multiple levels, and I would like to apply best subset selection method. I just wanted to make sure I interpret the result correctly.